# Error: implicit declaration of function `int open(...)'

Tags: c++, unix, gcc, solaris

I am using open function in one of my C++ project on Solaris OS.

```
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <fcntl.h>

char in_pathname[PATH_MAX];
int  in_fd = -1;
in_fd = ::open(in_pathname, (O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC), 0600);
```

Using the above line I am getting following compilation error.

implicit declaration of function `int open(...)'

Any idea why its happening.

Note: This source code is very old and I am using gcc version 2.95.3 to compile it.

Comment: It seems your compiler doesn't know your function (needs a declaration). Have you checked what you have included ? You need this : #include <fcntl.h>

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have included this header. Still getting this error.

Comment: Please post a minimal, *complete* example.

Comment: Thanks @molbdnilo. I have updated the code block.

Comment: Where is your compilation getting `fcntl.h` from?  What's in that file?  What's the output from `g++ -M source.cc`, where `source.cc` is your C++ source?  See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options for details on the `-M` option.

Comment: @itguru You can't have an assignment at file scope. Please post code that has no error other than the one you're mentioning.

Comment: I came to conclusion that because of following files inclusion, error is coming. #include <string>
#include <vector>    But don't know why ?

Answer (score 1):

Some (older) compilers will let you use a function you haven't declared and assume it returns int.

This will happen if you use a file but haven't included the header it is declared in. You seem to be using file's open method, and [these docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29032/open-2.html) suggest you therefore need

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have included these headers and still getting error.

Comment: Can you include enough code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I have edited the code block to add include headers and variables I am using. Thanks for you help

Comment: What if you call `open` rtaher than `::open`?

Comment: Just tried calling open instead of ::open. Same error :-(